# Fonts in modern website shows problems in every browser, how to solve?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

Platform: win7, x64, radeon hd7450, windows aero off, cleartype full off.

So, i tried any of major browsers and all they shows problems like that. in chrome problems persists too.

The problem is manifested in not clear fonts, heed that russian characters are looks good.

html4 websites fonts are ok, in this example checked site is youtube, but problems are happened in modern websites, i think google fonts are problematically, but not sure.

NOTE: firefox with overrided useragent ie6, is ok, all characters.

firefox useragent = ie6

[image: firefox useragent = ie6]

firefox default useragent.

[image: firefox default]

ie 8

[image: ie 8]

vivaldi

[image: vivaldi]

kmelon

[image: kmelon]

Comment: zoom full images to see differences, especially look at description and comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty much 'normal'. The issue is not with websites or browsers, but with Windows and the fonts themselves.

When your user-agent is "IE6", YouTube uses a simplified stylesheet with only basic fonts, such as Arial. When the user-agent is that of a modern browser, which can load fonts over the web, YouTube starts using its own fonts such as Roboto.

Traditionally, Arial and other fonts which came with Windows itself were optimized for low-resolution pixellated screens – the people who created Arial and Times New Roman actually spent time [aligning everything to the pixel grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting), using TrueType "hinting instructions", and in some cases even including bitmap versions for specific sizes.

(Skim through [The Raster Tragedy](http://www.rastertragedy.com/) to learn why it's necessary in the first place.)

But that has become less common, due to both ClearType and high-resolution LCDs – e.g. even Microsoft's own Consolas practically requires antialiasing / font smoothing to be drawn properly. Likewise with Roboto. And since practically everyone has antialiasing enabled, the Windows font renderer hasn't been made smart enough to try to 'auto-hint' fonts.

Comment: Personal opinion: If you ask the OS to show garbage, then that's what you get…

Comment: so it's not a bug, it's a "feature"? but why companies that create fonts and font rendering techniques doesn't care about all? (people with eye problems, for example, for them Aliased fonts looks better than anti-aliased.).. in few words this problem with fonts can't be solved as far as i dont enable cleartype? 
offtopic: many useful sites like stackexchange sites, and other informational, are ok, entertaiment sites are bad at this point..